How to setup Actor Neural Network in Keras for continuous action spaces
I have a problem with an actor critic model where I am trying to define the action distributions for an actor critic model. I am struggling to properly define the log_prob layer and keep getting a ValueError. I know I need to initially set the log_std as this defines how the model can explore but cannot seem to do this.
    def __create_actor(self):
        """ Create continuous actor neural network """
        mu_output = self.__layer_init(self.action_shape[0], std=0.01, activation='tanh')(self.shared_output)

        # Initialise log_std as trainable variable with initial value of -1.0 (std = exp(-1) ~ 0.3679)

        log_std = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.ones(self.action_shape[0]) * self.log_std_init, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)

        self.actor = Model(inputs=self.shared_input, outputs=[mu_output, log_std], name='actor')

I have already tried softplus layers but I do not think this is correct as I need to init the layers with some low probability value and then let them be trained as the model learns.
